# documents not appearing in a view

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I have created Notes documents by script and I want them to appear in a view.

I have the following selection formula for the view:

```
SELECT Form="formA" & status="X" & keyField = ""
```

If I check the view the documents do not appear in them. If I check the documents with help of ScanEZ, DocumentViewer or the Document properties box the documents match the criteria:

- they docs have these fields
- these fields have the correct values

if I change the selection formula to:

```
SELECT Form="formA" & status="X" & keyField != "SOMESTUPIDVALUE"
```

the documents appear in the view.

Note these docs are created by JAVA code and never opened in a Notes client.

Anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: From the Document Properties Box on the `keyField` field, what are the values of **Data Length** and **Field Flags**?

Comment: How are you creating the keyField value? Are you using a replaceItemValue?  Otherwise it's possible it's creating the field, but not populating the empty string you are looking for in your original view selection criteria. You might want to put in Char(32) (didn't check if that's the method for Java), but the ASCII character string for an empty space.

Comment: Maybe the UNK table needs to be updated to reflct the proper data type for keyField. You can use "Load Compact -C" for this.

Comment: Remove the selection formula to troubleshoot

Comment: Field Name: keyField
Data Type: Text
Data Length: 1 bytes
Seq Num: 8
Dup Item ID: 0
Field Flags: SUMMARY 

""

Comment: I added the field(s) via doc.replaceItemValue("keyField", "");

Comment: @PatrickKwinten there you go. Data Length should be 0 bytes and not 1. Make sure to rewrite your `doc.replaceItemValue` line manually. It might well be that your empty `""` seems empty but it’s not. If you initially copied something in there and then deleted it to be empty string, what you copied might have contained an invisible character that you didn’t not erase entirely

Comment: Null terminator treated as data, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got summary tags on those fields?
Set issummary on the note items

Comment: I have not set the fields in this way, just straight via doc.replaceItemValue("keyField", ""); I notice that the SUMMARY is set on the field via this method

Comment: the trick seems to be that I have to set the field as a notes item so Item textItem = doc.replaceItemValue("keyField", null);             textItem.setValueString("");             textItem.setSummary(true); The replaceItemValue way does add the field but somehow the view selection formula does not pick it up (even the document properties claim its an empty field with the issummary property set. Thanks for all the help !!!

Comment: It doesn't make any sense but good for you that you solved your issue

Comment: fields without issummary set do not show up in views. 
Replaceitemvalue does not set issummary sometimes, I cannot remember when but it sometimes doesn't set it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess, but I think you'll find that your Java code is setting the value of keyField to a single space character (" ") instead of an empty string "".  Try changing your selection formula to this:

```
SELECT Form="formA" & status="X" & @Trim(keyField) = ""
```

If that works, you can fix your Java code to eliminate the unwanted space between the quotes, and the selection formula will still work for both your existing documents and for documents created after the fix.

Comment: this is not the case: doc.replaceItemValue("keyField", "");

Comment: Copy the done to an empty NSF and create (don't copy) a view with the same selection formula. At least then you'll know if the problem is in the docs or in the DB/view. That's all I've got.

Comment: Docs. Not done. Apparently I can't edit my comments in the Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the view setting "Show response documents in a hierarchy" is set and the document you are creating is a response document. If this setting is true, response docs would only appear if parent document is also part of the selection.

Solution would be to also show parent docs or remove the $REF fields.